# Vaadin 14 grid multi-line cells

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I have quite long Strings in one column and I want to display them as multi-line cells in my grid. 
I'm using Vaadin 14 + Java and I tried to set CSS-Style Class for the specific column:

Java-Code:

```
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
public class RisikoGrid extends Grid<RisikoEntity> {

    public RisikoGrid() {
         setSizeFull();

         // add the column to the grid
         addColumn(Entity::getAttribute).setHeader("MyCol")
            .setFlexGrow(10).setSortable(true).setKey("mycolumn");

         // set CSS style class for the specific column
         this.getColumnByKey("mycolumn").setClassNameGenerator(item -> {return "grid-mycol";});

   }
}
```

CSS (shared-styles.css)

```
.grid-mycol{
    background: red;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

While I do see the class-name when I use the inspector in my webbrowser (chrome), the css is not applied.

[image]

What do I need to change to make it work?

Edit: this is how my styles look like - and I can't even see the background:red for instance:

[image]

Comment: how do your styles look like for grid-mycol? And are the shared-styles.css loaded by the browser?

Comment: other stuff is loaded from shared-styles and applied in other places of my webapplication.  What do you mean with "how my styles look like?" the css excerpt above?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I didn't see it in the question. How do the computed styles in Chrome look like? You should see why the styles are not applied

Comment: the weird thing is, that the background:red (and the other things I set in the css) don't show up anywhere in the css-inspector under "Styles". I added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into why my css settings didn't show up in the inspector and the solution was a minimal change from:

```
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
```

to

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/shared-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
```

I'm guessing the component scope of the grid differs from the global CSS.

It works now.

Comment: Yes, class names added using a ClassNameGenerator are added to the elements inside the Grid’s shadow DOM, and are not affected by global CSS.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in `wrap-cell-content` theme variant to allow text to wrap inside the cells.

```java
grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_WRAP_CELL_CONTENT);
```

See the last example on https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/html-examples/grid-theme-demos – the texts there are not that long, but if you make your browsers window narrow enough you’ll see some of the addresses wrap on two lines.

Comment: I'm guessing this affects all cells/columns of the grid? E.g. if I only want to apply it to some columns, then I will have to add it individually with the ClassNameGenerator?